# filter() and get() don't give correct GQLQuery results

Tags: python, google-app-engine, redirect, google-cloud-datastore, gql

So I'm building a small wiki using Google App Engine, where if you type in a URL like `/newpage`, it redirects you to it if it already exists, else it redirects you to `/edit/newpage/` where you can edit (or in this case, add) the contents of the page. After the editing, it redirects you to the page itself, i.e. `/newpage`.

Here's the code:

The table that holds the entries:

```
class Entries(db.Model):
    title = db.TextProperty(required = True)
    content = db.TextProperty(required = True)
    created = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add = True)
```

The app handlers:

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage),
                            ('/signup', SignUp),
                            ('/welcome', Welcome),
                            ('/login', Login),
                            ('/logout', Logout),
                            ('/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)', WikiEntry),
                            ('/edit/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)', EditWikiEntry)
                            ], debug = True)
```

The handler functions:

```
class WikiEntry(webapp2.RequestHandler):
def get(self, wiki_entry):
1   entry = Entries.all().filter('title =', wiki_entry).get()
2   # entry = db.GqlQuery("select * from Entries where title = 'hello'")
3   # logging.error(entry.title)
4   logging.error(entry)
5   if entry:
6       logging.error("inside if")
7       self.response.write(render_str('entrypage.html', entry=entry))
8   else:
9       logging.error("inside else")
10      self.redirect('/edit/' + wiki_entry)

class EditWikiEntry(webapp2.RequestHandler):
1    def get(self, wiki_entry):
2       self.response.write(render_str('edit.html', wiki_entry = wiki_entry))

3    def post(self, wiki_entry):
4       content = self.request.get('textarea')
5       if content:
6           e = Entries(title = wiki_entry, content = content)
7           e.put()
8       self.redirect('/' + wiki_entry)
```

`textarea` is the name of the textarea on the `edit` page.

And here is `entrypage.html`:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>{{ entry.title }}</title>
</head>
<body>
    {{ entry.content }}
</body>
</html>
```

So here's the problem: I typed in `/hello` and since it didn't exist, it redirected me to the `edit` page. I typed into the contents `<h1> Hello World </h1>`, hit Save but it redirected me to the `edit` page yet again (with the textarea blank). I went to the admin page and confirmed that there IS indeed an object with title and content as I had saved.

I tried debugging and found out the query function in line 1 of `WikiEntry` doesn't work. When I print out `entry` in line 4, it's `None`. When I manually put in the string `hello` into the query as in line 2 of `WikiEntry`, I do get an object out of line 4 and it redirected me to `entrypage.html`, but with nothing in it. When I tried printing out the title on the console itself as in line 3, it threw an `AttributeError`:

```
AttributeError: 'GqlQuery' object has no attribute 'title'
```

If the object has no `title` attribute, then how did it print the object in the first place?

```
<google.appengine.ext.db.GqlQuery object at 0x04766270>
```

I'm really confused and don't how to resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are performing a query to retrieve the WikiPage, at times (due to eventual consistency) the query will not find the page just created.

You need to spend some time reading up on Eventual Consistency, it is important to understand concept this when using the data store.

I suggest you consider using the wiki page name as the key of the Entries entity and then fetching by Key rather than by a query. This will guarantee you will always be able to retrieve the Entry just created.